# Return To Previous Page - Laravel 8 Project

Tags: laravel, url, laravel-8, laravel-routing

I have a dashboard that views categories using a paginator and therefore my url often looks something like: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/categories?page=1` on my `category.view` page.

[image: Viewing List of Categories]

When I click `Edit` it takes me to the category edit page.

[image]

On this page I have a `go back to categories` button.

[image: View Categories]

That `View Categories` button works fine if the edit category page was not refreshed/reloaded.

Here's the code for my `View Categories` button

`<a href="{{ url()->previous() }}" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="material-icons">arrow_back</i> View Categories</a>`

The problem I have is that if I was to refresh the `Edit Category` page or save some edits this `View Categories` button stops to work as intended because when I click it just refreshes and stay on the same `Edit Category` page.

I know that that is caused by the fact that in my browser history once `Edit Category` page is reloaded it becomes the last page in history and therefore will rightfully be the one to load.

How do I make my `View Categories` button takes me back to the last paginated page even after reloading/refreshing the current `Edit Category` page?

I've used : `<a href="{{ url()->previous() }}" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="material-icons">arrow_back</i> View Categories</a>`

`<a href="{{ URL::previous() }}" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="material-icons">arrow_back</i> View Categories</a>`

`<a href="history.back()" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="material-icons">arrow_back</i> View Categories</a>` and none of them works as intended.

I can make the `View Categories` button to go back to the categories page but the problem with that I have to make sure that it lands on the last visited `http://127.0.0.1:8000/categories?page=NUMBER`

**Please Note** : This is not a Controller, Component, Routing or web.php problem. All of that works fine. I just want my `Go Back` button to work well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was very useful [`Laravel Session`](https://www.w3adda.com/laravel-tutorial/laravel-session)

```
  public function index(Request $request){
        $categories = Category::latest()->paginate(5);
        //the following snippet creates persistent session variables
        $request->session()->put('page',$categories->currentPage());
        return view('orders.view',compact('orders'));
  }
```

Also changed the `View Categories` button from this:

`<a href="{{ url()->previous() }}" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="material-icons">arrow_back</i> View Categories</a>`

To this:

`<a href="{{ Session::has('page') ? '/categories?page=' . Session::get('page') : '/categories' }}" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="material-icons">arrow_back</i> View Categories</a>`

This button first tests if `$_SESSION['page']` was set and if so when clicked it assigned the last known value to `?page=`, as extra precaution, if for whatever reason the session value was not found the button will just redirect back to `category.view` which is the categories landing page.

This is exactly what I wanted to achieve and I was surprised to find that nothing native or built-in method exists because I've checked most public forums and re-checked the [Laravel Doc](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x) and found nothing to what I'm looking for.
Maybe the question was just not clear enough but I am sure I've provided enough material to give a clear picture of what I wanted to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I had somewhat of a similar issue and solved it by using this:

`return redirect()->back();`

However it is hard to tell you anything specific since you did not post any code.

Comment: I've added the code in question... the problem still persists on my side.

I've went through the [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x) but I still can't seem to find a solution that works.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly is your situation but you can try the following code as you already know the exact webpage to go with the right parameter :

```
Route::get('/view-category/{id}',[CategoryController::class,'view'])->name('view-category')
{{ route('view-category',[id]) }}
```

Comment: That's the problem exactly... I don't know the exact page to go to because I am using a paginator. Also I don't want to use route or create controllers just for this.

Something simple like a `{{{route(url()->previous())}}}` is what I am trying to achieve.
Thanks for your effort though.

Comment: Right, so I just saw images you poseted of the site. 
What I meant you know the 'exact webpage' which means you Can find the a way to remember the category which they are going to edit or  where they came from. You can either use DB or session/localstorage then retrive it by adding paranmeter in your url inside your a href. Then of course you need to clear those parameter when they got back to the page.

Comment: Take a look of this site, hope it helps. [link](https://8bityard.com/how-to-redirect-back-with-all-previous-parameters-in-laravel/)

Comment: I would suggest to please also add more test data for pagination purpose. At least you can see those pagination button and get its page value. (At least 2 pages.)

Comment: Yeah I am looking for something similar to what's is on the link you've shared. I see that there are ways to do it but from a great framework like Laravel, one would expect quite an easy, built-in option to achieve this. Thanks a lot.